# How to make OKHTTP post request without a request body?

Tags: android, http-post, okhttp

Is there any way to make a post request with OkHTTP that does not have a request body?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
    RequestBody reqbody = RequestBody.create(null, new byte[0]);  
    Request.Builder formBody = new Request.Builder().url(url).method("POST",reqbody).header("Content-Length", "0");
    clientOk.newCall(formBody.build()).enqueue(OkHttpCallBack());
```

Comment: The library should offer this through an easy interface, that's crappy interface design for a popular library and common use case. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 37):

This worked for me:

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(null, new byte[]{});
```

Comment: or `RequestBody.create(null, "")`

Comment: or `RequestBody.create("", null)`, if you're using the latest version and don't like deprecation warnings. :)

Comment: Try `"".toRequestBody()` or `"".toRequestBody("application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull())`

Answer (score 14):

I'm using `okhttp3`.

You can also do this for an empty request body:

```
val empty: RequestBody = EMPTY_REQUEST
```

For a `POST`:

```
val request = Request.Builder().url(http).post(EMPTY_REQUEST).build()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks

Comment: Using this EMPTY_REQUEST caused some weird ClassNotFound exception

Comment: `EMPTY_REQUEST` is in the internal package (`okhttp3.internal`), so it isn't intended to be used by library users. But you can simply declare the constant in your own code like this: `val EMPTY_REQUEST = ByteArray(0).toRequestBody()`.

Answer (score 7):

- `"".toRequestBody()`
- `"".toRequestBody("application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull())`

...depends on which media type your endpoint expects.

Comment: This answer is for kotlin btw. If the IDE doesn't recognize this, you must import the extension function: `import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.toRequestBody`

Answer (score 4):

The below method with the arguments has been deprecated in okhhtp3.

```
RequestBody.create(null, new byte[0])
```

The below solution worked for me.

```
RequestBody.create("", null)
Request.Builder().url(errorRetryUrl).post(RequestBody.create("", null)).build()
```