# GET request with request body in OkHttp

Tags: java, okhttp

I'm trying to use OkHttp 3.6.0 with Elasticsearch and I'm stuck with sending requests to the [Elasticsearch Multi GET API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/docs-multi-get.html).

It requires sending an HTTP GET request with a request body. Unfortunately OkHttp doesn't support this out of the box and throws an exception if I try to build the request myself.

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create("text/plain", "test");

// No RequestBody supported
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                  .url("http://example.com")
                  .get()
                  .build();

// Throws: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method GET must not have a request body.
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                  .url("http://example.com")
                  .method("GET", requestBody)
                  .build();
```

Is there any chance to build a GET request with request body in OkHttp?

*Related questions:*

- [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)
- [How to make OKHTTP post request without a request body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35743516/how-to-make-okhttp-post-request-without-a-request-body)
- [Elasticsearch GET request with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939748/elasticsearch-get-request-with-request-body)

Comment: have you found any solution for same?

Comment: @Hiren No, unfortunately not. Luckily I could resort to using `POST` requests instead of `GET` requests with body.

Comment: Ok no problem same here

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution for this problem after a few attempts. Maybe someone finds it useful.

I made use of "Httpurl.Builder."

```
HttpUrl mySearchUrl = new HttpUrl.Builder()
       .scheme("https")
       .host("www.google.com")
       .addPathSegment("search")
       .addQueryParameter("q", "polar bears")
       .build();
```

Your get request url will happen exactly this way:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=polar%20bears
```

And after building your url you have to build your request like this:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(mySearchUrl)
                        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                        .method("GET", null)
                        .build();
```

Here is the source: https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/HttpUrl.html

Comment: I don't see how this would send an HTTP request body in an HTTP GET request.

Comment: I'm sorry my friend. I'm looking to find a solution particularly for elasticsearch. But i couldn't how to customize "curl" with HttpUrl.Builder. I thought you can put your keys and values with in addQueryParameter("q", "polar bears") method instead of request body. Or may be you can make use of addPathSegment("search") method when build your url for your request. But i was wrong. It doesn't solves curl issues.

Comment: This solution sets query params and not the HTTP request body.

Answer (score 2):

Technically RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.3 says you can use the body in the get request.

What I tried before switching to another client library

1. I tried request rewriting using network interceptor
2. I tried reflection to change the method

   ```
       Field field = originalRequest.getClass().getDeclaredField("method");
       field.setAccessible(true);
       field.set(originalRequest, "GET");
   ```

**Conclusion**:
You will need to change the library, OKHttp doesn't have support for GET request with requests body,  need to use apache client or any other client which supports this.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the answer from @nilesh-salpe:

```
static class GetBodyBuilder extends Request.Builder {
    public Request.Builder get(RequestBody body) {
        this.post(body);
        try {
            Field field = Request.Builder.class.getDeclaredField("method");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(this, "GET");
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new SliceException("Couldn't set dirty reflection", e);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then, instead of doing

```
new Request.Builder().get(getBody(input))
```

We can do

```
new GetBodyBuilder().get(getBody(input))
```

It's not pretty, but it works

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna make get request with body, through OkHttp / Retrofit, use this working solution:

Instead of `@GET(...) / @POST(...)`

Do `@HTTP(method = "get", path = "/user/get", hasBody = true)` - use lowercase `get`!

So it's start look like:

```
@HTTP(method = "get", path = "/user/get", hasBody = true)
suspend fun transcripts(@Body request: TranscriptsRequest): TranscriptsResponse
```

Perfectly works!

Comment: Using lowercase get was the key, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

None of this solution works right now. I've used reflection to set the body for `GET` method, however then the request just failed with `socket closed` exception. They do not intend to fix this as describe in their [GitHub issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3154)

I suggest to migrate to other HTTP client like Apache or Java 11 HTTP client

Answer (score 0):

I tried to achieve the same, but unfortunately, it cannot be done without dirty tricks I personally admire as an exercise but don't want to see in my production code.

Basically, you can create POST method with a builder and set its method field to "GET" later using the reflection. This will do the trick.

Something like this:

```java
Builder builder = new Request.Builder().url(mySearchUrl).method("POST", body).build();
Field field = Builder.class.getField("method");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.setValue(builder, "GET");
```

Comment: give 'NoSuchFieldException: method'

Answer (score -1):

If the base API allow query params, send all the body params as queryparams. It works like a charm. While OKHttp allow the query params but will not allow  body with Get calls to avoid cache inconsistencies.

Comment: It doesn't, see [Multi Get API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/docs-multi-get.html). If query parameters were supported, I wouldn't have to ask the question. Also, the length of query parameters is limited, the size of a HTTP request body is not (within reasonable bounds).

Answer (score -1):

```
val url = "http://www.google.com/search".toHttpUrlOrNull()?.newBuilder()
            ?.addQueryParameter("q", "cat videos")
            ?.build()

val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()

    val request = url?.let {
        okhttp3.Request.Builder()
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer ${HeaderBearerKey}")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .url(it)
            .build()
    }

    if (request != null) {
        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {

                Log.i("xxx Fail", e.localizedMessage)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: okhttp3.Response) {

                response.body?.let {

                    val responseData = it.string()
                    Log.i("xxx", responseData)

                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

do both.  (in order)

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                  .url("http://example.com")
                  .post(requestBody)
                  .get()
                  .build();
```

Comment: This will reset the previously added request body: https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-3.6.0/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Request.java#L203